# Set only lower axis range in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, range

I want to set the lower value for the range of an axis and let the higher value to be automatic. Is this possible? I tried this:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy

x = numpy.linspace(0,1,99)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = x,
        y = 1/x,
        mode = 'markers',
    )
)
fig.update_yaxes(type='log', range=[numpy.log10(3),None])
fig.show()
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Works for me. What doesn't work for you?

Note that numpy.log10(3) = 0.4-ish. So not that much different from 0...

Comment: What about defining `y` as `y = 1 / x`, then for the range set as `range=[numpy.log10(3), max(y)]`?

Comment: @StephanT for me this code is the same as not setting the range at all.

Comment: @S3DEV yes I know, but I want it automatically as I am plotting stuff within a loop and don't want to take care of yet another extra thing. If there is no alternative I will default to that...

Comment: By the way, I have just upgraded to plotly-5.13.1 and its the same.

Answer (score 0):

Found some weird behavior indeed.

First: change the range to `x = numpy.linspace(0.01, 1, 99)` to get rid of the dividezero.

Then remove the log from your range, as the type already seems to force it to a Log. Then try `fig.update_yaxes(type='log', range=[1,3])` versus `fig.update_yaxes(type='log', range=[1,None])`